# Meaning of the "on"

Tags: meaning, prepositions, word-meaning

What does it mean "on"?

> I’ve never ever posted ***on*** here, but thought maybe today I would.

Comment: What is the source of this quote? It looks like a casual and not carefully written comment.

Comment: @JamesK it's from YouTube channel (youtube.com/user/SAMSTERBOH975/featured) in Community of the channel.

Comment: Youtube comments are not carefully edited.   Probably the writer started with "posted on this forum" but then changed "this forum" to "here" without removing the redundant "on".  Nothing special

Comment: @JamesK In your sentence is the word "edited" an adjective or a verb? adverb(carefully) + adjective is not it?

Comment: "edited" is a verb, it is part of a passive construction "are ... edited"  with a modifer "not carefully"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most general meaning of *X on Y* when talking about physical things is:

- X is above Y.
- X and Y are touching.
- If you move Y, X moves too - X and Y may or may not be attached.

The thickness of X and Y isn't important.  So, a cup can be *on* a table, a building can be *on* the ground, and you draw or write *on* a piece of paper.

Web technology is originally modeled after paper documents, even though they are very dynamic in nature on the modern Web.   When you post on a web *page*, your post then appears *on* the page.  Similar to how newspaper printers would print things *on* paper, or you would write a message *on* a postcard.